# Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$. Show that $\{a \in [0,1]: f(a)\neq 0\} = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \{a \in [0,1]: |f(a)|\geq 1/n\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$. Show that:

$$\{a \in [0,1]: f(a)\neq 0\} = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \{a \in [0,1]: |f(a)|\geq 1/n\}$$
 I just don't really know how to formulate a proof using definitions? My prof doesn't do examples and this is my first proof based class so I'm really lost. Like I could probably explain a good answer in words but I don't know how to mathematically prove it? Do you have any material I could learn from?

Comment: Just a tip for writing: use $\to$ instead of ---->. Use $\neq$ instead of =/ . Use $\geq$ instead of =>. And if you want to see how this comment would look like if it were written as a question, click on it and then click "render mathjax"

Comment: Another tip: Don't put the entire question in the title. Use a brief description for the title instead.

Comment: And instead of infinity use $\infty$

Comment: $\to$ is `\to`, $\neq$ is `\neq`, $\ge$ is `\ge`, and $\infty$ is `\infty`.

Comment: thank you @blue I'm sorry I don't know mathjax very well.

Comment: Is the equation correct now?

Comment: @Mathissohardlmao It's ok, you are here to learn. Now, have you tried thinking about this problem? Do you notice that $f\neq 0$ if and only if $|f|>0$?

Comment: yessir @projectilemotion I appreciate it. I'm sorry I'm still learning and the summary page didn't show me those.

Comment: @blue I noticed that. I just don't really know how to formulate a proof using definitions? My prof doesn't do examples and this is my first proof based class so I'm really lost. Like I could probably explain a good answer in words but I don't know how to mathematically prove it? Do you have any material I could learn from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After seeing [your comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3362692/let-f0-1-to-mathbbr-show-that-a-in-0-1-fa-neq-0-bigcup-n#comment6920485_3362692), I figured that I should help you figure out how to attack such problems.

The first thing you should do is notice that you are trying to prove the equality between two sets. That's the overarching "type" of problem you're dealing with here. The naive way to do this, i.e. the method following from the defintions, is to try to show that one set is a subset of the other. That is, to show $A = B$, we need to show that, if $x \in A$, then $x \in B$, and if $x \in B$, then $x \in A$.

So, let's assume that
$$x \in \{a \in [0, 1] : f(a) \neq 0\}. \tag{1}$$
We must now show that $x$ belongs to the infinite union:
$$x \in \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \{a \in [0,1]: |f(a)|\geq 1/n\}. \tag{2}$$
What does $(1)$ mean? It means we are allowed to assume $x \in [0, 1]$ and $f(x) \neq 0$.

What would $(2)$ mean? In order for $x$ to belong to an infinite union, it must belong to at least one of the sets in the union. That is, there would have to exist some $n$ between $1$ and $\infty$ such that
$$x \in \{a \in [0,1]: |f(a)|\geq 1/n\}$$
which is to say that $x \in [0, 1]$ (this is already a given, from our assumption $(1)$) and that $|f(x)| \ge 1/n$.

We need to establish the existence of something, in this case, a natural number $n$. What this often* means is that you need to **construct** such an $n$, which is to say, you need to figure out a recipe for turning your given $x$ into an appropriate choice of $n$ (depending on $x$).

Now that we have our assumptions unpacked, and we're more clear on our goal, let's try to bridge the gap. We know that $f(x) \neq 0$, but we want to know something about $|f(x)|$. One thing that $f(x) \neq 0$ tells us is that $|f(x)| > 0$; recall that $|y| \ge 0$ for all $y$, and is only equal to $0$ when $y = 0$.

So, we know there's a gap between $0$ and $|f(x)|$. We want to squeeze some $1/n$ between $0$ and $|f(x)|$. This really should be possible, if you think about it, because $1/n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. the terms of $\frac{1}{n}$ remain positive, but become arbitrarily small.

Now, how can we find such an $n$? We need a recipe for turning our given $x$ into an appropriate $n$. We want $|f(x)| \ge \frac{1}{n}$, which is equivalent to
$$n \ge \frac{1}{|f(x)|}.$$
If we could choose $n = \frac{1}{|f(x)|}$ we would be absolutely fine, except that $\frac{1}{|f(x)|}$ may not be an integer. However, this is not a problem: we just choose $n$ to be an integer larger than $\frac{1}{|f(x)|}$, e.g.
$$n = \left\lceil\frac{1}{|f(x)|}\right\rceil.$$
Now we have our recipe for $n$ in terms of $x$. So, for any $x$ satisfying $(1)$, we can absolutely construct some $n$ such that $x$ and $n$ satisfy $(2)$.

That's how my mind worked out the given argument, but this is not a tight, well-presented proof yet! This is how I would write it out:

> Suppose
>   $$x \in \{a \in [0, 1] : f(a) \neq 0\}.$$
>   Note that $f(x) \neq 0 \implies |f(x)| > 0$. Let
>   $$m = \left\lceil\frac{1}{|f(x)|}\right\rceil.$$
>   Since $|f(x)| > 0$, we have $\frac{1}{|f(x)|} > 0$, and hence $m$ is a positive integer. Further,
>   $$m \ge \frac{1}{|f(x)|} \implies |f(x)| \ge \frac{1}{m},$$
>   hence
>   $$x \in \{a \in [0, 1] : |f(x)| \ge 1/m\},$$
>   and therefore,
>   $$x \in \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{a \in [0, 1] : |f(x)| \ge 1/n\}.$$
>   Thus,
>   $$\{a \in [0, 1] : f(a) \neq 0\} \subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{a \in [0, 1] : |f(x)| \ge 1/n\}.$$

Note, I only showed one set was a subset of the other. You should show also that the union is contained in the other set. I'll let you write this one up.

I will get you started by saying that you should start by assuming that $x$ exists so that $(2)$ is satisfied, and you should work towards showing $(1)$ is true. From $(2)$, you may now *assume* the existence of some $n$ such that
$$x \in \{a \in [0, 1] : |f(x)| \ge 1/n\}.$$
Good luck!

---

*There are plenty of examples of "non-constructive" existence proofs that don't fit this mould, but trying to construct an explicit example of the desired object is usually the first thing you should try doing when attempting an existence proof. With some experience, you can learn to spot when a non-constructive technique better suits the problem at hand, but you can worry about that *much* later!

Comment: I appreciate this so much! Thank you, I was so stressed out. This math is so different than what I'm used to. I got A's in calc 1/2 and this has honestly destroyed my confidence in only two weeks haha.

Comment: @Mathissohardlmao I'm not 100% sure what is in calc 1/2, but if it's anything like my schooling, I'm guessing they're calculus courses which focus on computation methods rather than proofs? You should know, the shift to proofs is rough for almost everyone. It's a total paradigm shift in how you think about mathematics. I've always thought the transition could be done more smoothly, and proofs could be taught better, but I'm just not really sure how. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Take $x\in[0,1]$ such that $f(x)\neq 0$. Then $|f(x)|>0$ and thus there exist $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $0<\frac{1}{n}\leq|f(x)|$. We conclude that $$x\in\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty}\left\{ a\in[0,1] : |f(a)|\geq\frac{1}{n}\right\}$$Now take $x\in \bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty}\left\{ a\in[0,1] : |f(a)|\geq\frac{1}{n}\right\}$. Then, by definition, there exist $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|f(x)|\geq\frac{1}{n}>0$. Then $|f(x)|>0$, i.e., $f(x)\neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Instead of thinking about the set $\{a\in[0,1]\mid f(a)\ne0\}$, consider that the subset of the reals given by $\{b\in\Bbb{R}\mid b\ne0\}\cap f([0,1])$ is equal to the *image* of your desired set.

If you can show that $\{b\in\Bbb{R}\mid b\ne0\}=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb{N}}\{b\in\Bbb{R}\mid |b|\ge\frac{1}{n}\}$, then the *preimage* of the intersection of either set with $f([0,1])$ must be equal to $\{a\in[0,1]\mid f(a)\ne0\}$.