# Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$. Show that $\{a \in [0,1]: f(a)\neq 0\} = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \{a \in [0,1]: |f(a)|\geq 1/n\}$ (Proof Verify)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

> Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$.
>
> Part A: Show that:
>   $$\{a \in [0,1]: f(a)\neq 0\} = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \{a \in [0,1]: |f(a)|\geq 1/n\}$$
>
> Part B: Assume $M$, a positive constant exists such that for any finitely many distinct numbers $a_1,\dots,a_n\in[0,1]$
>
> $|f(x_1)+...f(x_n)|\le M$
>
> Show that the set $$\{a \in [0,1]: f(a)\neq 0\}$$ is countable.

**Attempt:**

Part a)

Let $x \in[0,1]$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$
then $|f(x)|>0$
and $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that 
$0<1/n\le f(x)$.

Now there must exist a $x \in\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \{a \in [0,1]: |f(a)|\geq 1/n\}$
$n\in \mathbb{N}$ must then exist such that $|f(x)|\ge1/n>0$.

Part B (I didn't know how to complete this)

Facts: A set $E$ is countable if there exists an injective mapping from $f:E\to\mathbb{N}$
Also, every finite set is countable by definition.

from a) we know:

$0<f(a)\le |f(a_1)+...+f(a_n)| \le M$

Now I'm not really sure if I'm done now? The set seems like its bounded from both sides and $a_1..a_n$ is a finite set by definition? I don't know how to finish

This question is different from my last one in that I forgot to add part b). I'm sorry.

Comment: The Part B statement is not clear. Is it written correctly? What is the property of  such $M$ and $a_1,\dots,a_n$?

Comment: Why do you ask the same question again? See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3362692/let-f0-1-to-mathbbr-show-that-a-in-0-1-fa-neq-0-bigcup-n

Comment: In B) the $M$ does not appear in the rest of the statement.

Comment: @RobertZ This one has a part b on it I forgot to add it on the last question!

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Fixed, I'm sorry

Comment: @RobertZ Fixed!